# React: How to capture focus when a focused child component unmounts

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component which can get focus. It uses this focus to offer keyboard controls. This parent component can spawn a child component which similarly can take focus so that it can respond to keyboard events. One of the keyboard events that the child component listens for is `<esc>` which causes the child component to get unmounted.

When the child component unmounts, focus is returned to the `<body>` of the document.

**How can my parent component detect when this happens and reassign focus to itself?**

What I know so far:

- React's synthetic `onBlur` handler *does* get bubbled blur events from it's children (unlike non-synthetic events). But, blur events are not triggered when the element with focus leaves the DOM.
- React does not implement a `onFocusOut` listener, but if I register one directly using a ref, I do get an event telling me that the child has unmounted. However, I can't distiguish between a `focusout` event triggered by a child unmounting, and a `focusout` event triggered by a user clicking into a different click target.

*Edit*: I’m looking for a solution that doesn’t involve direct communication/coupling between the parent and child components. Imagine that there might me arbitrarily many children like this in an arbitrarily deeply nested tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this using a MutationObserver.

The code looks like this:

```
// It's possible for a child component to gain focus and then become
// unmounted. In that case, the browser will return focus to the `<body>`.
// In the following hook, use a `MutationObserver` to watch for that behavior
// and refocus the containing FocusTarget when it happens.
//
// I tried a number of other approaches using `focus/blur/focusin/focusout` on
// various DOM nodes, and was unable to find a solution which would trigger in
// this senario in Firefox. Therefore we use this `MutationObserver` approach.
useEffect(() => {
  // Only create the `MutationObserver` within the currently focused target.
  if (ref == null || windowId !== focusedWindowId) {
    return;
  }

  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    // In the common case we won't have focused the body, so we can do this
    // inexpensive check first to avoid calling the more expensive `O(n)`
    // check of the individual mutations.
    if (document.activeElement !== document.body) {
      return;
    }
    if (mutations.some(mutation => mutation.removedNodes.length > 0)) {
      ref.focus();
    }
  });

  observer.observe(ref, {
    subtree: true,
    attributes: false,
    childList: true
  });

  return () => observer.disconnect();
}, [windowId, focusedWindowId, ref]);
```

Actual commit adding it: https://github.com/captbaritone/webamp/commit/2dca07ff0a97ad378a1a050513255d2ba129dbcd

Answer (score 1):

The child component should accept a function prop that gets called when `esc` is pressed (or wherever else it needs to be called).

```
// Render function of Parent
const functionThatGetsCalledWhenEscIsPressed = function(){
  this.input.focus();
}

return (
  <div>
    <Child onDestroy={functionThatGetsCalledWhenEscIsPressed} />
    <input ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I’ve edited my question to clarify that I’m looking for a solution that doesn’t involve tight coupling between the parent and the child.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback from the parent to the child to be called in the case that the `<esc>` key is pressed (or just in the `componentWillUnmount` method of the child). This callback can just transfer focus to the parent, in the same manner that happens usually.

For example:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    focusSelf() {
        // do stuff to focus self
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child beforeUnmount={ this.focusSelf }/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    componentWillUnmount() {
        const { beforeUnmount } = this.props;
        beforeUnmount();
    }
}
```

Comment: I’ve edited my question to clarify that I’m looking for a solution that doesn’t involve tight coupling between the parent and the child.

Comment: @JordanEldredge hmm, you might be able to do that using a global state solution with the Context API or Redux. But do you just want to avoid the tight coupling between Parent and Child just to handle arbitrary depth? or are there other reasons?

Comment: The reason I want to avoid coupling is simply architectural. It does not seem sustainable to ask all engineers (or me next month) to remember to opt into this system every time they add a focusable element.